# WordPress,не работает плагин Elementor

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-плагины

Всем привет, ребята, такая проблема, занимаюсь сайтом на WP,нужно добавить новые страницы,сайт сделан полностью на плагине Elementor,но я не могу с помощью него добавить страницы тк он не запускается,предлагает включить безопасный режим и на этом все,бесконечная загрузка если кто знает как это решить,велком!буду безумно признателен.Гуглил, что может из за такой ошибки SSL не работать плагин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пробейте запустить плагин, а не заниматься удалением гланд через заднее функциональное отвертсвие. Жмакаем ф12, смотрим ошибки консоли. А лучше переустановить плагин, написать им в поддержку. 

или пиратская версия?

Comment: Я с  WP На вы)не подскажите,если переустановить плагин,все настройки слетят?нет,купленая

Comment: Ничего не должно слететь. Но нужно понять где ошибка. посмотрите на ошибки в консоли браузера.

НО! Сделайте бекап, вдруг что слетит)

Comment: хех)спасибо попробую!

Comment: Попробуйте отключить по очереди все плагины